# how to providing json data in code given by w3 autocomplete https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

Tags: javascript, html, json, django, api

I m trying to provide data from database so i am sending data through JSON format through link example:-127.0.0.1:8000/test which is working well
but i want to use those data which is in JSON format in this code
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp
instead of var countries

this code is provide my w3school (a autocomplete java script code)

my test api output:

```
"[{\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 1, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"swift\"}}, {\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 2, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"wagonr\"}}, {\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 3, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"baleno\"}}, {\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 4, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"breeza\"}}, {\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 5, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"spresso\"}}]"
```

after parsing with var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

```
[{"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 1, "fields": {"car_model_new": "swift"}}, {"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 2, "fields": {"car_model_new": "wagonr"}}, {"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 3, "fields": {"car_model_new": "baleno"}}, {"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 4, "fields": {"car_model_new": "breeza"}}, {"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 5, "fields": {"car_model_new": "spresso"}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the map function, iterate over the array and retrieve the model names in an array. I have updated my answer and also added inline comments where you are making an AJAX request. I  have also shown what is the issue with your data.
Hope it will resolve your issue. Please let me know if it fixes.

```js
/* This is the dataset provided by you. It is like JSONed twice. The best solution would be change into JSON. */

var myArr = "[{\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 1, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"swift\"}}, {\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 2, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"wagonr\"}}, {\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 3, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"baleno\"}}, {\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 4, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"breeza\"}}, {\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 5, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"spresso\"}}]";

/* You should convert it into JSON like below. No need of extra quotes around the array and unnecessary backspaces. Commenting below code as you want to work with your own data. */

/*
var myArr = [
{"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 1, "fields": {"car_model_new": "swift"}}, 
{"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 2, "fields": {"car_model_new": "wagonr"}}, 
{"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 3, "fields": {"car_model_new": "baleno"}}, 
{"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 4, "fields": {"car_model_new": "breeza"}}, 
{"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 5, "fields": {"car_model_new": "spresso"}}
]
*/

function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
              b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
      x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
    }
  }
}
/*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
});
}

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  /* Find JSON.parse twice because your JSON data is also stringified. */
    var myArr = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    const carModelsArr = myArr.map((d) => d.fields.car_model_new)
    autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), carModelsArr)
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px Arial;
}

.autocomplete {
  /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}

.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208458/discussion-on-answer-by-jasdeep-singh-how-to-providing-json-data-in-code-given-b).

Answer (score 0):

myArr[0]["fields"].car_model_new; // for the first car model

```
  for(var i =0; i < myArr .length; ++i) { output.push(myArr[i]["fields"].car_model_new) }
```

I have got the array of car models by typing this to the console

```
    var myArr = [{"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 1, "fields": {"car_model_new": "swift"}}, {"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 2, "fields": {"car_model_new": "wagonr"}}, {"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 3, "fields": {"car_model_new": "baleno"}}, {"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 4, "fields": {"car_model_new": "breeza"}}, {"model": "core.newcarmodel", "pk": 5, "fields": {"car_model_new": "spresso"}}];
    var output = [];
    for(var i =0; i < myArr .length; ++i) { output.push(myArr[i]["fields"].car_model_new) }
    console.log(output);
```

Comment: doesnt give any output i tried .......i also tried myArr[0]["fields"] which give me undefined output

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the response?